# How to assert for an error using axios and async / await

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs, axios

I am trying to write a test that asserts that a specific type of error is thrown with Async / Await and axios. However, when I run my test, I get the following. Why is jest not properly rejecting my promise? Thanks!

> Error: expect(received).rejects.toThrow()
>
> Expected received Promise to reject, instead it resolved to value
>   {"data": "response", "status": 404}

**api.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import SpecialError from './specialError.js';

const get = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('sampleUrl', { withCredentials: true });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new SpecialError(error);
  }
};

export default get;
```

**specialError.js:**

```
export default class SpecialError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.isSpecialError = true;
  }
}
```

**api.test.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import get from './api';
import SpecialError from './specialError.js';

test('testing the api get method', async () => {
  axios.get.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
    data: 'response',
    status: 404,
  }));

  const expectedError = new SpecialError('foo');

  await expect(get()).rejects.toEqual(expectedError);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`axios.get` is mocked to resolve to an object so `get` resolves to that object.

It looks like you are testing the error case, in which case `axios.get` should be mocked to reject:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import get from './code';

test('testing the api get method', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockRejectedValue(new Error('error'));
  await expect(get()).rejects.toThrow('error');  // Success!
});
```

---

**Update**

OP updated the question to ask how to test for a specific kind of error.

You'll probably want to throw the error like this:

```
try {
  // ...
} catch (error) {
  throw new SpecialError(error.message);  // <= just use the error message
}
```

...and `SpecialError` should probably pass its args to `super` like this:

```
export default class SpecialError extends Error {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);  // <= pass args to super
    this.isSpecialError = true;
  }
}
```

...but given those changes you can test like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import get from './api';
import SpecialError from './specialError.js';

test('testing the api get method', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockRejectedValue(new Error('the error'));
  const promise = get();
  await expect(promise).rejects.toThrow(SpecialError);  // <= throws a SpecialError...
  await expect(promise).rejects.toThrow('the error');  // <= ...with the correct message
});
```

Note that testing for a particular error type *and* message is a bit tricky since [`toThrow`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) lets you check for one or the other, but not both at the same time.  You can get around this limitation by testing for each individually.

Comment: Thanks @brian-lives-outdoors! Please see the edits. My goal is to actually write a test to make sure that my `get` method throws a specific kind of error. How would I be able to assert this?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how to test for a specific kind of error @Jimmy